# работа с двумерным ассоциативным массивом

Tags: php, массивы

есть такой массив `$_SESSION['pr']`

```
array(1) {
  ["7b"]=>
  array(3) {
    [7]=>
    int(1)
    [9]=>
    int(1)
    [8]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

пробую перебрать его следующим образом

```
foreach($_SESSION['pr'] as $k => $v){ 
    $cat = $k;
    foreach ($_SESSION['pr'][$cat] as $key => $value){    
        $id = $value; 
//тут вывод   
    }

}
```

Не получается выводить `$cat` единожды. Если выводить его внутри второго цикла, то выводится трижды. Нужно что бы получилось как то так

`$cat." ".$id`. В данном случае вот так `7b 7` `7b 9` `7b 8`. Что бы потом передать в хтмл. Сейчас выводится `7b7b7b 7` и тд

Comment: `        foreach ($v as $key => $value){    
            $id = $value; 
    //тут вывод   
            echo "$cat $id <br/>";
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
foreach($_SESSION['pr'] as $cat => $value){ 
    foreach ($value as $id => $v){    
       echo $cat . " " . $id . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: получилось, спасибо.Перепутал значит ключ со значением